# Handle relationships in REST

Tags: http, rest, restful-architecture

I'm learning how to make a good REST API. So, suppose I have the following models:

```
Post
    has title, body, publish_date
    has_many comments, authors

Comment
    has author, publish_date
```

So, if I call `GET /post`, to get all posts, how it's comments should be returned? I'm thinking in something like:

```
{
    'post/1': {
        'title': 'My first post',
        'body': 'a big body',
        'publish_date': '20121120',
        'comments': 'post/1/comments',
        'authors': 'post/1/authors'
    },
    'post/2': {
        'title': 'Another post',
        'body': 'a REALLY BIG body',
        'publish_date': '20121121',
        'comments': 'post/2/comments',
        'authors': 'post/2/authors'
    }
}
```

I'm also thinking in put each comments' resources direct in `/post` response, like

```
'comments': {
    'post/1/comment/1',
    'post/1/comment/2',
    'post/1/comment/3'
}
```

So, what's the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each post "owns" its comments, you could simply send the comment data with the post data:

```
{
    'post/1': {
        'title': 'My first post',
        'body': 'a big body',
        'publish_date': '20121120',
        'comments': [/* comment data here */],
        'authors': 'post/1/authors'
    },
    'post/2': {
        'title': 'Another post',
        'body': 'a REALLY BIG body',
        'publish_date': '20121121',
        'comments': [/* comment data here */],
        'authors': 'post/2/authors'
    }
}
```

You might want to do the same with authors. Rule of thumb: as a consumer of your API, I don't want to have to keep making API calls to get all of the relevant data. If response size/time is a concern, at least give me the *option* to get post-relevant fields; also consider response pagination.

Comment: So, it's ok to bundle related data in a single response, if all are related, right? I don't want to force my API clients to make several requests too, though.

Comment: _"So, it's ok to bundle related data in a single response, if all are related, right?"_ You're designing the API. Whatever you allow is "okay" by definition. Doing this seems reasonable, though. It's exactly what my answer suggests. _"I don't want to force my API clients to make several requests too, though." – I don't see what you're getting at. Bundling related data in a single response _reduces_ the number of requests clients would have to make.